# Don't understand the Numpy Boolean indexing documentation

Tags: python, numpy

I am running a very simple example -

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
mask= np.array([True, False])
a[mask]
```

This produces `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 5 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2`.

The confusion arises from my understanding (or lack thereof) of this part of [Numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing): -

> If `obj.ndim == x.ndim, x[obj]` returns a 1-dimensional array filled with the elements of `x` corresponding to the `True` values of `obj`. The search order will be row-major, C-style. If `obj` has `True` values at entries that are outside of the bounds of `x`, then an index error will be raised. **If `obj` is smaller than `x` it is identical to filling it with `False`**. (emphasis mine)

I thought  the `mask` array would be transformed to `[True, False, False, False, False]` but seemingly that is not the case. Also, both `a` and `mask` have same `ndim` value, so why would error message say `a` has dimension 5 but boolean dimension is 2.

What am I missing? How do I interpret the doc?

Comment: the 5 and 2 in your error is the length of the dimension along dimension 0. The wording could really be better tbh^^

Comment: I wonder if this is a documentation error, that hasn't kept up with releases.  numpy has been cleaning up things like this.  I would make sure boolean matches in size.

Comment: You're missing nothing, the documentation is wrong and the error message uses *dimension* inconsistently. I can't remember a time when this would have been correct.

Comment: we need to search the release notes.

Comment: Please consider filling an issue on the [github of Numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3A%2204+-+Documentation%22+mask) so to help future users (and likely fix this probable error / wording issue).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny There's a GitHub issue [#4980](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4980) regarding this. Apparently, this was the intended behaviour in version 1.8 and earlier. This has been since deprecated. Probably, they forgot to update the documentation.

Comment: @Ch3steR That issue has been closed. I think a new issue could be raise to update the documentation AND fix the error message (because it is also incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.13, mask size must match

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.13.0-notes.html#boolean-indexing-changes

```
Boolean indexing changes
Boolean array-likes (such as lists of python bools) are always treated as boolean indexes.

Boolean scalars (including python True) are legal boolean indexes and never treated as integers.

Boolean indexes must match the dimension of the axis that they index.

Boolean indexes used on the lhs of an assignment must match the dimensions of the rhs.

Boolean indexing into scalar arrays return a new 1-d array. This means that array(1)[array(True)] gives array([1]) and not the original array.
```

In v 1.20, there was a further small correction to require matching shape as well as size.

The line you quote appears to be a left over from an earlier time where the size match was not enforced.

Most often the boolean mask is constructed by doing some comparison on the array itself, so the size match is automatic.  People don't normally construct short mask - except by mistake or to test the documentation.

Comment: It'd be good if you also mention about the rather incorrect error message.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the use of `dimension` in doc is not consistent, probably due to deprecated content in the old version.

You might regard boolean index as "take the element at the position(`True`) or not(`False`)", so the shape of `obj` and `x` shall be the same, as mentioned in [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)